Extern Controller, Cannot connect to Webots instance
I installed ROS2 on WSL2, Ubuntu22.04, and follow the tutorial in this link, which helped me install webots on Win11.
But when I execute this command ros2 launch webots_ros2_universal_robot multirobot_launch.py, the output is as follow.
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/... 
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [webots-1]: process started with pid [33219]
[INFO] [webots_controller_my_robot-2]: process started with pid [33221]
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 50 seconds...

The output of console in webots is INFO: 'my_robot' extern controller: Waiting for local or remote connection on port 1234 targeting robot named 'my_robot'.
After using Ctrl+C in the terminal, here is the ERROR.
[ERROR] [webots_controller_my_robot-2]: process has died [pid 44428, exit code 1, cmd '/home/.../ros2_ws/install/webots_ros2_driver/share/webots_ros2_driver/scripts/webots-controller --robot-name=my_robot --protocol=tcp --ip-address=127.0.0.42 --port=1234 ros2 --ros-args -p robot_description:=/home/.../ros2_ws/install/my_package/share/my_package/resource/my_robot.urdf'].
[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[ERROR] [webots-1]: process has died [pid 44426, exit code 1, cmd '/mnt/d/Program Files/Webots/msys64/mingw64/bin/webots.exe --port=1234 \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\tmp\tmplt0x31sh_world_with_URDF_robot.wbt --batch --mode=realtime'].

I thought it was an ip-address mistake, which cause the extern controller connection error. Because there was no ip-address like 127.0.0.42 via ipconfig /all.
Here is one similar bug report I found in github, but this maybe not the point.
System

Webots Version: R2023b (WEBOTS_HOME="/mnt/d/Program Files/Webots")
ROS Version: Iron

Operating System

Host: Win11
Guest: wsl2, Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Iron installed

Thanks a lot!!!

P.S.
After I delete the .wslconfig file I copy from learn.microsoft.com, the error changed as follow:
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] Error: The connection was closed by Webots. The robot is already connected or your IP address is not allowed by this instance of Webots.
[webots_controller_my_robot-2] [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

I checked the firewall in win11, and the two boxes of both webot-bin are checked.
